PIC32 USB CDC always one message behind
I'm using a PIC32MZ2048EFM144 on a curiosity 2.0 board. The project is written using MPLAB X IDE v6.20. Complier is XC32 v4.45. Harmony 3 with MCC.
I have a fully working composite USB device with HID and CDC. Both devices work. The problem is with the CDC device. Its messages are always one behind. Here is what I mean.
On the board there are 4 test buttons. The buttons are set to send a message when the button is pressed and released. (they are de-bounced) When I push button 1 nothing is sent. When I release button 1 a message that button 1 is pressed arrives. Then I push button 2. A message that button 1 is released arrives.
        case APP_CDC_STATE_CHECK_FOR_WRITE_COMPLETE:
        {
            /* Check if the write is complete */
            if ((appData.cdcDataAvailableToSend == true) && (appData.appCOMPortObjects.isWriteComplete == true))
            {
                appData.cdcDataAvailableToSend = false;
                appData.appCOMPortObjects.isWriteComplete = false;
                unsigned int size = 0;
                size = outgoing_buffer_get_total();
                int i = 0;
                unsigned char data;
                while (outgoing_buffer_get(&data))
                {
                    appData.cdcWriteBuffer[i] = data;
                    i++;
                }
                USB_DEVICE_CDC_Write(appData.cdcInstance, &appData.writeTransferHandle, 
                    appData.cdcWriteBuffer, size, USB_DEVICE_CDC_TRANSFER_FLAGS_DATA_COMPLETE);
            }

        }
            appData.cdcState = APP_CDC_STATE_CHECK_IF_CONFIGURED;
            break;


The messages I'm sending are 20 to 30 bytes long tops. The USB driver returns that the write completed properly. The call to USB_DEVICE_CDC_Write() includes the flag USB_DEVICE_CDC_TRANSFER_FLAGS_DATA_COMPLETE. Per documentation this should initiate the send.

/* This flag indicates there is no further data to be sent in this transfer
and that the transfer should end. If the size of the transfer is a
multiple of the maximum packet size for related endpoint configuration,
the function driver will send a zero length packet to indicate end of the
transfer to the host. */

Even if the message was 64 bytes this flag should automatically send a zero length packet.
I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I need to somehow flush the buffer after each transmission?
Minimum viable project for curiosity 2.0 board
In the project LED1 (red) will flash at a rate of 1 second on 1 second off. This is the heart beat. LED2 (green) will illuminate when any of the 4 buttons are pressed and go out when released. The buttons send a, b, c, and d when pressed. Open a terminal and connect to the board. Open any word processor and make sure the focus is on it. Press and hold button 1. The green led will illuminate. The letter a will appear in the work processor, it will start to repeat, but button1pressed will not appear in the terminal. Release button 1. Green led will go out. The letter a will stop repeating. Button1pressed will appear in the terminal.

Are you sure that your debouncing solution does not have this issue? Did you check this independently, for example with a toggled port pin and an oscilloscope?

Instead of the buttons, I'd write a test program that sends messages on a time base, differentiated by intervals, just to make sure that the USB stuff works correctly.

Anyway, please [edit] your question to add a minimal, complete, and reproducible example. Otherwise we can only guess, and that is very inefficient.

@thebusybee There are test LEDs on the board. It turn on when the button is held down and turns off when the button is released. Also the project sends the button presses via HID. If I put the terminal side by side with the custom app I have. The app will show the button press and the terminal won't. Further demonstrating that it is not the debounce.

@thebusybee I edited the post and added a link to a minimum viable project. Because it uses harmony the project is not very minimum.
